# Tomodachi Life Mii level cap?

Tags: tomodachi-life

What is the level cap for a Mii in Tomodachi Life?

Also when a mii reaches the maximum level, is there a message that says the Mii is at the maximum level just like on the first time a Mii reaches level 20 when the message says you can give hats and clothing at level up?

Answer (score 2):

No, when a Mii reaches the maximum level(they will still level up but it will stop counting past 99!), there won't be a message that says it reached 99 unlike when a 
Mii reaches level 99.

Answer (score 0):

The max level is 99, yet there is no special message (aside from 'Level Up') when they reach that level.

When their happiness bar is filled up on Lv. 99, the message 'Level Up' will appear again, although they didn't actually gain a level. (They will still be Lv. 99, not Lv. 100)